# NPAPI : How to read the return NPError value of NPP_New in javascript

Tags: javascript, npapi

We are developing a Netscape plugin for Safari in Mac
I have a scenario in which the initialization done in NPP_New function fails and I am returning NPERR_GENERIC_ERROR. How can i read this error code in Javascript.

Any help in this regard would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have to fail in NPP_New? Couldn't you succeed and allow script to ask the plugin about it's state later?

Comment: George, there is a condition at startup in NPP_New failing which i should not load plugin. In that case i have to check the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to identify this specific failure scenario i can think of the following options:

- succeed NPP_New, but set the plugins internal state accordingly (so script can ask the plugin about it later)
- move the initialization in question out of NPP_New and let it be invoked through a scriptable function (... `ret = plugin.initStuff()`)
- if you absolutely have to fail in NPP_New (e.g. because there is no supported drawing model on OS X) you could call into the page, informing script about the condition

Comment: Thanks George, What do you mean by set the plugins internal state? Please pardon my ignorance. How can we set the plugins internal state?

Comment: I just meant remembering that you failed and the failure reason. Given that and not failing NPP_New, you could e.g. expose the failure reason as a property.

Answer (score 1):

The error code from the C NPAPI call isn't available in JS. However, if you already know what the error code is, then you don't really need to read it--just try to access some scriptable property of your plugin in a try block, and if it fails you know that your plugin didn't load.

Comment: Worth noting that this doesn't allow for differentiation between the original scenario, the plugin not being installed or the plugin being blocked (flashblock, blocklist, ...).

Comment: Detecting whether it's not installed/enabled is easy enough, since you have JS access to the plugin list. Agreed that doesn't help with click-to-play and other blockers though.